# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition, total noob

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand this is probably a really REALLY silly problem, but I've only just started using SQL since Monday. Originally I was using an access database and converted it to SQLExpress and now I'm getting that error. Included are some screenshots that will hopefully show you how I've messed up.
[The Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN6DY.png)

[The Database in SQL Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpTYQ.png)

Comment: the `Data` table has 2 columns....and you are inserting just one...

Comment: Please post code and error message as **text** inside your question, do not use images. And please remove the self-deprecation (like "total noob" and describing your own problem as "REALLY silly", it doesn't help and actively detracts people.

Comment: To build on @Lamak comment, do you want to insert a value into both columns in the table? If so, you need to specify two values (in this case, two columns in the select). If not, you need to change the first line to `INSERT INTO Data$ (CompItemNo)` to specify the column you are inserting the 1 value into. It's a good practice to list the columns in the insert to begin with in case the structure changes you are pre-emptively avoiding this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing an insert in Sql you need to either provide a list of the columns you are inserting into or provide values for all columns in the table.
Since your insert is providing one value and your table has two columns you would need to provide a list containing the column for which you are providing values.

```
insert into Data$ (CompItemNo)
Select CompItemNo
From Kits$
where ItemNo = :ItemNo;
```